# Angular ng-repeat creating random gaps + Foundation

Tags: css, angularjs, zurb-foundation, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="moive in movies" class="columns large-1">
    <a href="#/movies/{{moive.imdbID}}">  
      <img ng-src="/data/images/{{moive.imdbID}}.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am getting json data and viewing the image url as gallery.

Some how ng-repeat create random gap between these images in random column (the same as `<br>` effect). Its for every 20 images, it does skip a line automatically.

I don't have any custom css implemented except foundation.

What seems to be a problem?

Comment: just a tip, may be you should call your ng-repeat variable `movie` not `moive`

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co) to reproduce the issue so we can play around? Is this in all browsers or just one?

Comment: Have you also checked that there are no empty objects in your json data?

Comment: I think it is because of the 'columns large-1' classes, try removing them and see if it is the problem

Comment: Are you trying to wrap every 20 images? Create a minimal example like this http://codeply.com/go/HTJ2RIS4UO so that we can understand what you want.